# Android : Wanted but not invoked , Actually , there were zero interactions with this mock

Tags: android, mockito

Writing test cases for ViewModel.

In which, viewmodel perform operation using repo which contains datasource. 
Error occurs at  mDataSource.getWorks(callback)

ViewModel :

```
            mObsIsShowProgress.value = true
            mRepo!!.getWorks(object :DataSource.WorksListCallback {
                override fun onWorksListReceived(works: List<Work>) {
                    mObsWorksList.value = works;
                    mObsIsShowProgress.value = false
                }

                override fun onFailure(error_code: Int, reason: String) {
                    mObsIsShowProgress.value = false
                }


            })
```

Repo :

```
class Repo(dataSource: RetrofitDataSource):DataSource {

    var mDataSource: RetrofitDataSource = dataSource
    override fun getWorks(callback: DataSource.WorksListCallback) {
        mDataSource.getWorks(callback)
    }


}
```

ViewModelTest:

This test is meant to check the works are loaded or not.

```
     // Executes each task synchronously using Architecture Components.
            @get:Rule
            var instantExecutorRule = InstantTaskExecutorRule()
            @Mock
            private lateinit var worksRepostiory: Repo
            @Mock private lateinit var context: Application

            @Captor
            private lateinit var loadWorkCallbackCaptor: ArgumentCaptor<DataSource.WorkListCallback>


            private lateinit var worksViewModel:ViewModel

            private lateinit var worksList: List<Work>

         @Test
            fun loadWorksFromRepository_dataLoaded(){
          // When loading of works is requested
                worksViewModel.getWorks()
      // Callback is captured and invoked with stubbed works
                verify<Repo>(worksRepostiory).getWorks(capture(loadWorkCallbackCaptor))

          // Then progress indicator is shown      


   assertTrue(LiveDataTestUtil.getValue(ViewModel.mObsIsShowProgress))

             loadWorkCallbackCaptor.value.onWorksListReceived(worksList)


        }
```

Comment: fixed it by sending mocked workRepository

Answer (score 1):

You have to do your setup first then you have to state the expected behavior like when(something).thenReturn(result) for example before you call the method you would like to test. Finally, you assert the expected result, like assertEquals(expectedresult, yourmethodreturnedresult).

```
@Test
fun loadWorksFromRepository_dataLoaded(){
    //method to test
    worksRepostiory.getWorks(loadWorkCallbackCaptor)

    //test
    loadWorkCallbackCaptor.value.onWorksListReceived(worksList)
    verify<Repo>(worksRepostiory).getWorks(capture(loadWorkCallbackCaptor))
    assertTrue(LiveDataTestUtil.getValue(ViewModel.mObsIsShowProgress))
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably put things in the wrong order.  verify doesn't check if something is ever called-  it checks if it has *already* been called.  You probably want the verify last.